# CORS on Stripe https://js.stripe.com

Tags: stripe-payments, svelte, http-status-code-400

I have been trying to integrate stripe elements on my sapper framework.

I am using this library [svelte-strip-js](https://github.com/joshnuss/svelte-stripe-js), all steps work fine but I have started to see these issues continuously on my console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://r.stripe.com/0' from 
origin 'https://js.stripe.com' has been blocked by
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
POST https://r.stripe.com/0 net::ERR_FAILED 400
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) NetworkError: https://r.stripe.com/0
    at XMLHttpRequest.r.a.g.onreadystatechange
```

My guess is this has something to do with the content security policy. I followed the stripe [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide) and have created a CSP that suits my use case after verifying from [this](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/) evaluator

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
     content="
        connect-src * https://api.stripe.com;
        frame-src https://js.stripe.com https://hooks.stripe.com;
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://js.stripe.com;
        object-src 'none';
     "
    />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that this was a known configuration issue on Stripe’s end and a fix was deployed. You shouldn’t be seeing these errors anymore. From what I can tell from Stripe’s discord server threads regarding these errors, `r.stripe.com` is just for tracking metrics so it should not have any impact on the ability to make payments.